# Why needs more than 2 elements to be vertically aligned using line-height property?

Tags: html, css

I needed to vertically align an inline-block element and came across an example on the Internet using line-height property.

The code as follows:

HTML

```css
div#line-parent {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  text-align: center;
}

div#line-parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.line-child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: brown;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="line-parent">
  <div class="line-child">
    vertical align using line height
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if the parent (`#line-parent`) contains only the child (`.line-child`), then the child is not vertically aligned in middle.

In order to get the child to be vertically aligned in the parent, I either added speudo class `:before` in the parent (as I did above) or added some text in the parent.

I want to know why we need to add more than elements in order to get those elements vertically aligned? How does that work?

Comment: Did not get your point. Well if you will remove before still child div will be in center.

Comment: It is centered once you remove the :before element.

Comment: I found the problem is that I did not add <!DOCTYPE html> at the beginning of the HTML file. And the code did not work if I added the DOCTYPE as <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">. Isn't line-height property supported since CSS 1.0

Comment: If you leave out the doctype declaration, the browser displays the page in quirks mode. One of the quirks is that inline-block elements are aligned differently in blocks, yes. (Usually demonstrated with images in table cells, that have no space for the descender in quirks mode.)

Comment: And if you use the Transitional doctype, the page is displayed in "almost standards mode", which is also a kind of quirks mode; albeit with fewer quirks, but it still has this one. And I'm not making this up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common misconception that `vertical-align` refers to the position of an inline level element *within* a parent.

**This is not the case.**

`vertical-align` refers to the alignment of multiple inline level elements ***to each other*** within such a container.

From the [**W3 Spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)

> The inline-level boxes are aligned vertically according to their 'vertical-align' property. In case they are aligned 'top' or 'bottom', they must be aligned so as to minimize the line box height.